# How to generalize a method inside a class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class called `MinPQ` (priority queue) which works on generic data called `Item`. Out of the `greater()` method, other methods are doing work on the indexes of the `items`.
The `greater()` method is comparing two different items - see bellow.
This method will work fine for any standard data type (`Item` = `int`, `float`, etc...) but what about a user defined object?

How can I modify this `MinPQ` class and the `greater()` method in order to take into account a more general Object?

The `MinPQ` class:

```
template <class Item> class MinPQ
{
private:
    Item *items;
    int N;
    int queueSize;

    void resize(int capacity);
    void swim(int k);
    bool greater(int i, int j);
    void exch(int i, int j);
    void sink(int k);    

public:

    MinPQ();
    MinPQ(const MinPQ &pq);//copy constructor
    ~MinPQ();

    void insert(Item item);
    Item min();
    inline int size(){return N-1;}
    inline bool isEmpty(){return size() == 0;}
    void print();
};
```

the constructors:

```
template <class Item> MinPQ<Item>::MinPQ(const MinPQ &pq)
{
    N = pq.N;
    queueSize = pq.queueSize;
    items = new Item[queueSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        items[i] = pq.items[i];
}

template <class Item> MinPQ<Item>::MinPQ()
{
    queueSize = 2;
    items = new Item[queueSize];
    N = 1;
}
```

The `greater()` method:

```
template <class Item> bool MinPQ<Item>::greater(int i, int j)
{
    return items[i] > items[j];
}
```

Comment: Do you basically want to compare two elements of type `Item` just like you compare ints?

Comment: why are you not using `std::vector<Item>` to store your variable length buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the definition of `SomeItem` you can specify that operator `>` will do with two items:

```
struct SomeItem
{
    //item stuff
    int item_property;
};

bool operator > (const SomeItem & a,const SomeItem & b)
{
    return a.item_property > b.item_property;
}
//after this you can compare items based on item_property.

//...
MinPQ<SomeItem> a;
a.greather(0,1);//this will work as long as types used int MinPQ will have operator >
```

Or you can overload the operator directly inside the type:

```
struct SomeItem
{
    //item stuff
    int item_property;
    bool operator > (const SomeItem & other)const
    {
        return item_property > other.item_property;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 but just change `Item` to some other name like `SomeItem`. because `Item` is used in the template...

Comment: also `item` can overload the `operator>`